# Passing string list to javascript function Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, javascript-objects

Im building my first Django app.
I want to call a javascript function that receives a list of strings.
In my current version Im sending a Django object (called provider) property like this and it´s working fine:

```
<a href="#" class="button secondary tiny" onclick="download_provider_files('{{ provider.full_name }}')"><i class="fi-download"></i></a>
```

But now I want to call a Provider model method that returns a list of strings, so then I can do something with this list in Js method

```
def get_provider_files_urls(self):
        provider_files = self.provider_files.all()
        file_list = []
        for f in provider_files:
            file_list.append(f.file.name)
        return file_list
```

I tried this:

```
<a href="#" class="button secondary tiny" onclick="download_provider_files('{{ provider.get_provider_files_urls }}')"><i class="fi-download"></i></a>
```

and got this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to generate a JS array from a list is to use the [`join`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join) filter

```
onclick="download_provider_files(['{{ provider.get_provider_files_urls|join:"', '" }}'])"
```

Probably cleaner to use the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter though

Comment: I have to adapt it a little bit but now is working. Thanks!! I will take a look also at json_script  <a href="#" class="button secondary tiny" onclick="download_provider_files(['{{ provider.get_provider_files_urls|join:', ' }}'])"><i class="fi-download"></i></a>